# How to apply password to pdfs in Batch?

Tags: security, pdf, passwords, batch-processing

I have 2,000 pdf documents in SharePoint and they are very sensitive. How do I password the PDF files but all in one batch. I am not sure having Acrobat X reader and Acrobat XI Pro helps. Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like there is a way but I can only select 1 file at a time and apply security which is not going to work. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/921014

Comment: I almost got it work but still facing the challenge when Adobe keeps prompting for Check Out and Check In for every file. Acrobat has a good feature but is not full fledged. I would truly appreciated it if someone know a way to suppress the check-out & check-in prompts